# Laravel Redirect Back with() Message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying to redirect to the previous page with a message when there is a fatal error.

```
App::fatal(function($exception)
{
    return Redirect::back()->with('msg', 'The Message');
}
```

In the view trying to access the msg with

```
Sessions::get('msg')
```

But nothing is getting rendered, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: fix typo Session`s`, and add `use` where needed. Apart from it - should work.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Try

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'The Message']);
```

and inside your view call this

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Comment: This works, how cool.
But why wont this work 

     `return Redirect::back()->with('msg', 'The Message');`

how to get the "msg" here ?

Comment: Have you tried to see if the message is there? `Session::has('msg')`

Comment: Yes checked `Session::has('msg')` and the 'msg' is not there.

Comment: Try instead of `->with()` the `Session::flash()`.

Comment: It doesn't work, the frustration is that `withErrors` does the same thing i.e. `$this->with('errors', new MessageBag((array) $provider));`

But still if I try to access $msg with `with('msg', 'The Message')` then it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different *key* or pass an array instead. Use also `Session::put()`.

Comment: @StackOverflowed Isn't this exactly the same with my answer and the cause of this conversation?

Comment: @giannischristofakis It sure seems like it. I have no idea what I was smoking that cold foggy morning in September.

Comment: **For 5.4**, `withErrors('some error')` - so needs to be a string instead of array.

Comment: In Laravel 8: `App\Http\Controllers\Redirect` not found.

Comment: Use this `withErrors(['msg'=> 'The Message'])` this is working for me.

Answer (score 202):

> **Laravel 5 and later**

**Controller**

```
 return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your message,here');
```

**Blade:**

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>{!! \Session::get('success') !!}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Array to string conversion :(

Comment: Comment left as edit: If it gives Error : Array to String Conversion, then just small fix in **controller** `return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your message here');`

Comment: @Michael What do you mean if? It definitely returns an array!

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk -- it isn't my comment. Another SO user had edited the answer when he should just have left a comment here or created his own answer.

Comment: @Michael we should edit the answer in the right way because if you run that code it won't work.

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk Not according to [meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) leave a comment instead or make a correct answer.

Comment: Fixed! Now it returns a string. Enjoy

Comment: we have session() and cookie() helpers to use in your blade files instead of Facades I don't know why lot of people don't like helpers.

Comment: This one worked in Laravel 9. In controller I have used:
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Quantity Constraint Failed');            


Inside blade of redirected  location, I put

    @if(session()->has('message'))
              <p class="alert alert-success">{{session('message')}}</p>
    @endif

Comment: @Rajib thanks, I used your code and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 81):

Alternative approach would be

Controller

```
use Session;
       
Session::flash('message', "Special message goes here");
return Redirect::back();
```

View

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
   <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 28):

In Laravel 5.4 the following worked for me:

```
return back()->withErrors(['field_name' => ['Your custom message here.']]);
```

Comment: Hi. The accepted answer is for use in Laravel 4 (see the question tag), the parameters for the `withErrors()` method in the answer is an array with two elements: `['msg', 'The Message']`. See the api for acceptable parameters: https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_withErrors

Comment: In my answer, for use in Laravel 5.4, the parameters for the `withErrors()` method is an array with one element that is a `key => value` pair, where the value is an array. 5.4 API: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_withErrors

Answer (score 13):

You have an error (misspelling):

```
Sessions::get('msg')// an extra 's' on end
```

Should be:

```
Session::get('msg')
```

I think, now it should work, it does for me.

Answer (score 12):

Just set the flash message and redirect to back from your controller functiion.

```
    session()->flash('msg', 'Successfully done the operation.');
    return redirect()->back();
```

And then you can get the message in the view blade file.

```
   {!! Session::has('msg') ? Session::get("msg") : '' !!}
```

Comment: I think `{!! Session::get("msg", '') !!}` should be enough. `get()` already checks if the _key_ exists and returns the default value otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

**In Laravel 5.5**:

```
return back()->withErrors($arrayWithErrors);
```

In the view using Blade:

```
@if($errors->has())
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: $errors->has()   was fail but $errors->any() work well

Answer (score 9):

**For Laravel 5.5+**

**Controller:**

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your message here');
```

**Blade:**

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ Session::get('success') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This works for me in Laravel 8

Answer (score 8):

In laravel 5.8 you can do the following:

```php
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['name' => 'The name is required']);
```

and in blade:

```
@error('name')
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 6):

#Laravel-9
Inside the blade where this redirection back action initiated

```
   return redirect()->back()->with('message', "The Message");
```

Inside the blade where this form, will be returned after the above action

```
                @if(session()->has('message'))
                <p class="alert alert-success"> {{ session()->get('message') }}</p>
                @endif
```

Answer (score 5):

**in controller**

For example

```
return redirect('login')->with('message',$message);
```

**in blade file**
The message will store in session not in variable.

For example

```
@if(session('message'))
{{ session('message') }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but this answer might help somebody out there.

In Laravel 8.x this is what worked for me: You can return the error to the previous page or to another page.

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['password' => ['Invalid Username or Password']]);
```

This will also work:

```
return view('auth.login')->withErrors(['username' => ['Invalid Username or Password']]);
```

Please ENSURE, however, that the page/view you are returning has a field name that corresponds to the first parameter passed in the withErrors method (in this case, username or password) and that the @error directive in your view references the same field like this

```
@error('password') //or @error('username')
 <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
 </span>
@enderror
```

for example

Hope this helps somebody. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I stopped writing this myself for laravel in favor of the [Laracasts package](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) that handles it all for you. It is really easy to use and keeps your code clean. There is even a [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch/episodes/12) that covers how to use it. All you have to do:

Pull in the package through Composer.

```
"require": {
  "laracasts/flash": "~1.0"
}
```

Include the service provider within app/config/app.php.

```
'providers' => [
  'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider'
];
```

Add a facade alias to this same file at the bottom:

```
'aliases' => [
  'Flash' => 'Laracasts\Flash\Flash'
];
```

Pull the HTML into the view:

```
@include('flash::message')
```

There is a close button on the right of the message. This relies on jQuery so make sure that is added before your bootstrap.

**optional changes:**

If you aren't using bootstrap or want to skip the include of the flash message and write the code yourself:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
  <div class="{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
    {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

If you would like to view the HTML pulled in by `@include('flash::message')`, you can find it in `vendor/laracasts/flash/src/views/message.blade.php`.

If you need to modify the partials do:

```
php artisan view:publish laracasts/flash
```

The two package views will now be located in the `app/views/packages/laracasts/flash/' directory.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the 100% solution**

**Above mentioned solutions does not works for me but this one works for me in laravel 5.8:*

```
$status = 'Successfully Done';
return back()->with(['status' => $status]);
```

and receive it as:

```
@if(session()->has('status'))
     <p class="alert alert-success">{{session('status')}}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: The solution will work perfectly with 5.8 just try doing it like this.

**Controller**


return back()->withErrors(['yourfieldname' => 'yourerrormsg.']);


**Blade**


@error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
@enderror

Answer (score 4):

It works for me and Laravel version is ^7.0

on Controller

```
return back()->with('success', 'Succesfully Added');
```

on Blade file

```
@if (session('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
         {!! session('success') !!}
      </div>
@endif
```

For documentation look at [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects)

Answer (score 3):

#### For laravel 5.6.*

While trying some of the provided answers in Laravel 5.6.*, it's clear there has been some improvements which I am going to post here to make things easy for those that could not find a solution with the rest of the answers.

STEP 1:

Go to your Controller File and Add this before the class:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

STEP 2:
Add this where you want to return the redirect.

```php
 return Redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'The Message']);
```

STEP 3:
Go to your blade file and edit as follows

```php
@if (Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-error>{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
 @endif
```

Then test and thank me later.

This should work with laravel 5.6.* and possibly 5.7.*

Answer (score 3):

In blade

```
 @if(Session::has('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert">
        <strong>Success:</strong> {{Session::get('success')}}
    </div>

@elseif(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert">
        
        <strong>Error:</strong>{{Session::get('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

In controller
for success

```
 return redirect()->route('homee')->with('success','Successfully Log in ');
```

for error

```
 return back()->with('error',"You are not able to access");
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem and this worked.

Controller

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(array('user_name' => $message));
```

View

```
<div>{{{ $errors->first('user_name') }}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

laravl 8

```
Route::post('/user/profile', function () {
// Update the user's profile...

return redirect('/dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

Blade syntax

```
@if (session('status'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('status') }}
</div>
@endif
```

[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not working on laravel 9. am i missing something

Answer (score 1):

**For Laravel 3**

Just a heads up on @giannis christofakis answer; for anyone using Laravel 3 replace

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

with:

```
return Redirect::back()->with_errors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 5.6.***

*Controller*

```
if(true) {
   $msg = [
        'message' => 'Some Message!',
       ];

   return redirect()->route('home')->with($msg);
} else {
  $msg = [
       'error' => 'Some error!',
  ];
  return redirect()->route('welcome')->with($msg);
}
```

*Blade Template*

```
  @if (Session::has('message'))
       <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
           {{Session::get('message')}}
       </div>
  @elseif (Session::has('error'))
       <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
           {{Session::get('error')}}
       </div>
  @endif
```

Enyoj

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when I tried to redirect as:

```
public function validateLogin(LoginRequest $request){
    //

    return redirect()->route('sesion.iniciar')
            ->withErrors($request)
            ->withInput();
```

When the right way is:

```
public function validateLogin(LoginRequest $request){
    //

    return redirect()->route('sesion.iniciar')
            ->withErrors($request->messages())
            ->withInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.8**

*Controller*

```
return back()->with('error', 'Incorrect username or password.');
```

*Blade*

```
  @if (Session::has('error'))
       <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
           {{Session::get('error')}}
       </div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Try This**
    
    Try This Code 
    --- Controller ---

    return redirect('list')->with('message', 'Successfully');
    return redirect('list');
   
  ----  Blade view ------
    @if(session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session()->get('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As of laravel 9.19, If you use **Session::flush()**, It will delete all of your session data so you should use Session::put().

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
Session::put('msg', 'The Message');

If you want to store the data in an array use,
Session::push('msg','The message'); This will return an array in your view.
```

You can now access the session data in your view with the **session()** helper function. In your case that will be:

```
session('msg')
```