# laravel : redirect()->back()->with() not sending any messages

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, redirect

I did as directed according to the answer provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message) 
but it **didn't work** for me . So i reasked this question.
my controller is

```
public function save() {

        $med_group = MedicineGroup::create(Request::all());

        if ($med_group) {
            $this->setServerMessage('MedicineGroup created successfully');
            return Redirect::to('admin/user/create')->with('flashmessage',$this->getServerMessage());

        }
    }
```

I have made setServerMessage() and getServerMessage() in Controller.php

```
public function setServerMessage($messagearray) {
        if (is_array($messagearray)) {
            $type = $messagearray['type'];
            $html = "<div style='height:auto;padding:7px 0px 6px 20px;margin:0px' class = 'pull-left text-left col-md-8 alert alert-{$type}'>{$messagearray[0]}</div>";
        } else {
            $html = "<div style='height:33px;padding:7px 0px 6px 20px;margin:0px' class = 'pull-left text-left col-md-8 alert alert-info'>{$messagearray}</div>";
        }
        $temp = '';
        if (\Session::get('SERVER_MESSAGE')) {
            $temp = \Session::get('SERVER_MESSAGE');
        }
        \Session::put('SERVER_MESSAGE', $temp . $html);
    }

public function getServerMessage() {

        if (\Session::get('SERVER_MESSAGE')) {
            $temp = \Session::get('SERVER_MESSAGE');
            \Session::forget('SERVER_MESSAGE');
            return $temp;
        } else
            return "";
    }
```

my view is setup like this

```
<div class="box-footer text-right">
                @include('flash')
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value='Save'>
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" value='Reset' />
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
            </div>
```

and in my flash.blade.php i have written

```
@if(isset($flashmessage))
   {!! $flashmessage !!}
@endif
```

what did I miss? i followed [this site too](http://laraveldaily.com/all-about-redirects-in-laravel-5/) but i can't flash a message in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Set the flash message and then redirect to desired route

**Controller:**

```
  session()->flash('msg', 'Successfully done the operation.');
  return Redirect::to('admin/user/create');
```

Now get the message the in view blade file

**Blade**

```
 {!! Session::has('msg') ? Session::get("msg") : '' !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this thing, I am replacing your entire code, you can change it according to your need:

```
public function save()
{
    $med_group = MedicineGroup::create(Request::all());

    if ($med_group) {
        //$this->setServerMessage('MedicineGroup created successfully');

        // flash method to be used when just printing the message
        // on the screen. Link below
        \Session::flash('key', 'Your message here...');

        return Redirect::to('admin/user/create');

    }
}
```

In your view file:

```
@if(Session::has('key))
    {{ Session::get('key') }}
@endif
```

[Link for more information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
every other thing seems to be fine except for your layout 

laravel would escape the variable you are passing into the session while using this 

@if(isset($flashmessage))
   **{!! $flashmessage !!}**
@endif

you should do this instead 

@if(isset($flashmessage))
   **{{ $flashmessage }}**
@endif
```

Comment: nope .. didnot work . If I do dd($this->getServerMessage()) inside Controller I can see my flash message but Why can I not print that very message inside flash.blade.php And So strange thing is I **cannot print**  it even inside create() function on same Controller where I am redirecting it to.

Comment: this is why you wont get the message \Session::forget('SERVER_MESSAGE'); your are removing the message from the session read more about sessions here https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session