# Laravel return back with post data

Tags: php, laravel, post

i'm developing a web app with Laravel. I'm new with this amazing framework and i'm still learning.

My problem: i would to use

```
return back();
```

at the end of a method of controller, but passing to the back page some post data.

Example of what i want to do:

```
return back()->withPostData(['id'=>'10']);
```

Is possible to do that with Laravel?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message

Answer (score 3):

You can try as:

```
Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

From the docs..

> To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the [`old`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input)
>   method on the `Request` instance:

```
$id = $request->old('id');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use session to pass the data:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('id', 10);
```

And then get data with `session('id')`.

But if you're using forms and just want to get old data, you should use simple redirect and [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input) method:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="{{ old('id') }}">
```