# validator wont pass any $errors to blade

Tags: laravel, validation

I am trying to validate an from with this code:

```
            $this->validate($request, [
            'address' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'address.required' => 'Endereço Invalido',
            'quantity.required' => 'Quatidade Invalida'
        ]);

        return back()->withErrors("test123");
```

When I dont fill the form fields it returns to the form page with no errors, but when I filled it it return with the test123 error, what am I doing wrong on the validate here ? :\

Note: as people are responding me with soluctions to  return back()->withErrors("test123"); my problem is not with the return, that is just a test that I use to know if the $errors array was beeing filled correctly to the blade template, my problem is with $this->validate() that is not passing the $error array to the blade template

Comment: Try back()->withErrors(["error" => "test123"]);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back with() message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array within `withErrors()`

Comment: my problem is not on return back()->withErrors("test123"); that was just a test to see if $errors got filled, my problem is with validate, that is working (as it returns if the fields are not filled) but is not backing with the proper errors

Answer (score 0):

Validation errors are bound to views that have the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware attached to them.

Could it be that your route isn't in the 'web' middleware group?

E.g.: Note the `->middleware('web');`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware('web');
```

More reading here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: All my routes are on routes/web.php they should have the ShareErrorsFromSession on them, also the back()->withErrors("teste"); is working well

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a code example of what a route that has the 'web' middleware group looks like.