# Laravel - Redirect with variable to twig page

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, laravel-5, twig

I've made a mail function with an try/catch situation. It checks if the mail template exists, if not it needs to return redirect / back to the page with a message(`return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', "Mail doesn't exists");`)

Is it possible to redirect with a variable using a twig page? Or is there just something that I am doing wrong?

This is my mail function(DashboardController.php)

```
 public function MailContact($date_id, $contact_id)
{
    try
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($contact_id);
        $date = Date::find($date_id);
        $mail = Mails::where('datetype_id', $date->datetype_id)->first();
        $html = $mail->html;

        Mail::to($contact->email)->send(new Anniversary($html));

        return redirect('dashboard');
        }
    catch(\Exception $ex )
    {
        return redirect('dashboard')->with("Mail doesn't exists");
    }
}
```

This is the twig page('dashboard.twig')

```
 <div class="box-body no-padding" style="width: 100%; padding-top:20px;">
  <ul class="telephoneKingList" style=" display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;">
        {% for dates in datestodayUser %}
           {% if dates is not empty %}
              <li data-id="{{ dates.id }}">
                 {{ dates.contact.fullname }}, {{ dates.contact.relation.company }} <br>
                 {{ dates.description }}<br>
                 {# Place where Error needs to be #}
                 <a role="button" id="edit-button" href="/dashboard/mail/{{ dates.id }}/{{ dates.contact.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
              </li>
              <hr>
           {% endif %}
           {% else %}
              <li>
                 Geen data beschikbaar.
              </li>
           {% endfor %}                         
  </ul>
```

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with(['message'=>"Mail doesn't exists"]);
```

and then in your twig

`{{message}}` will give you the message

Comment: Works, thanks.{{ $message }} should be {{ message }} tho

Comment: Oops missed that one, also accept the same if worked

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
redirect('dashboard')->withErrors(["Mail doesn't exists"])
```

and in your twig you need to access the errors using

```
{{ errors.first() }}
```

Laravel has a middleware included out of the box called `ShareErrorsFromSession` which shares the session errors with all views.