# Return redirect with $errors in an if-statement

Tags: php, laravel

I think its a simple question to answer for you guys. I just want to redirect to the given page when serialnumber has an error but it tells me that $errors is undefined so i thought i have to add something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

but i coulndt find something like that what did i miss can anyone help me? :)

```
if ($errors->has('serialnumber')){

        return redirect()->route('borrow.index')
                         ->with('warning','Test');

}
```

EDIT:

I would like that with no matter what error you get rejected with a message on the page I have specified. With a single message that I define myself. The link in the comments wont help me out......

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message. Take a look here

Comment: Wont help me out....

Comment: where the $errors coming from?

Comment: From my view so i thought i could use it in the controller.
@if($errors->any())
                            <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
                            @endif

Comment: @Devi no you cant. as errors. how ever you can use a validator with defined error response

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation), The `$errors` variable is bound to the view by the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware, which is provided by the `web` middleware group.

As you shouldn't do redirects from your views, just check your condition inside your controller instead of your view.

Comment: I dont know how to validate errors thats why i questioned here and posted my code cause everything what i found couldnt help me. Thanks for the answer anyway then the error makes sense but i dont know how to do it like i want to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect with a specific error you can use you can use this from the Laravel documentation:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
                'body' => 'required',
            ]);
```

then get the errors :

```
$errors = $validator->errors();
```

or redirect when validator fails :

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // your redirect here...
}
```

Comment: I got this: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fails does not exist. And yeah i have already this in my code: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Comment: Can you help me please? ):