# validating inputs in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate input quantity of an item in Laravel. How will I do this using `request()->validate([])`? I want to validate if the `input` quantity from user is `greater` than the quantity of item from `database`.

Also, is it possible to return an `error` message if the `entered quantity` is `greater than` the quantity from database?

**Here's my validation, I know this is wrong.**

```
public function deduct(Request $request)
{

    $item = Inventory::findOrFail($request->itemid);
    request()->validate([
        'quantity' => $item->quantity > $request->quantity
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Check the item first from the database and set a condition.

Comment: please recheck post @RakibulIslam

Comment: I think this link will help you  if you not find item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message

Answer (score 0):

You can use min, max and digits_between

```
   $rules = ['test' => 'digits_between:2,5'];
```

or

```
   $rules = ['test' => 'numeric|min:2|max:5'];
```

Comment: please recheck post sir

Answer (score 0):

Set `$item->quantity` is the minimum value.

```
public function deduct(Request $request)
{

    $item = Inventory::findOrFail($request->itemid);
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'quantity' => 'min:'.(int)$item->quantity
    ]);

}
```