# Blade not showing messages on the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with showing error messages or session messages in laravel.

Comment the bootstrap cdn, but makes no differences.

have code like this, works correctly, refreshing the view, but not displaying errors:

Controller.php

```
return redirect()->route('trainers.show',[$trainer])->with('status','Entrenador actualizado correctamente');
```

blade.php

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('status')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

---

Controller.php

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max: 10',
            'avatar' => 'required|image',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
```

blade.php

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicated problem. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message

Comment: if you refresh the page, the flashed session vars are gone at that point, they are only available on the next request from when they are flashed ... unless you mean something else by refreshing the view

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the session status, you can use `\Session::has('status')` and `\Session::get('status')`, like so:

```
@if(\Session::has('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ \Session::get('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

And on your errors, you can also use `has()`, like so:

```
@if ($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```