# I can't display error messages in blade after I get 422 error

Tags: php, laravel, exception, http-status-code-422

I'm new to the whole concept of exception or error handling in laravel. Basically I have form request which, when rules aren't met, shows me 422 error in console, I want to convert that into error message in blade, but I fail.

I already tried this in Exception/Handle.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Invalid data');
//        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

My error message in blade should work with this:

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        {{ Session::get('error') }}
        @php
            Session::forget('error');
        @endphp
    </div>
@endif
```

I know that I should check error codes or instances before returning, but I just want to get this working. I can't return anything (no response at all).
One think which works is `return parent::render($request, $exception);` and it thows error message in console

**So more info**

I don't know if it helps, but the request is made from Vue application to controller, which takes FormRequest as a parameter.

Also, I can't check error code, I tried

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception->getCode() === 422) {
            return response([], 356); //should throw 356 error
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception); // instead this return fires and gives me 422 error
    }
```

**Vue component**

my template:

```
<template>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="submit()">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext textField"
               placeholder="Post a comment" required v-model="textField">
        <button :disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit">Post</button>
        <button :disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-dark submit" type="reset">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

my axios method:

```
                    axios
                        .post('/comments', {
                            textField: this.textField,
                            id: this.id,
                            routeName: this.routename,
                        })
                        .then(response => {
                            this.name = '';
                            this.callReload(this.id);
                            this.textField = '';
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Redirect Back with() Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message)

Comment: I tried every solution in your provided answer without luck, the problem probably is not about syntax, but approach, I can log to console any error code like so `return response([], 389);`, but can't redirect or make a response in json format

Comment: Can you provide the code for your vue component.

Comment: Of course, component does the job without errors if rules of form request are met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change the `render` function, which I assume is from `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` to return `JSON` for exceptions where the request was made via `JSON`.

```
public function render($request, $exception)
{
  if ($request->isJson()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Detail'], 422);
  }
}
```

You will also want to check the `exception` type rather than simply returning a 422 status code for any JSON exception.

Comment: But I actually had to do `return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Detail'], 200);` in order to access message,  422 status just throws an error.

Comment: Also I intended to display error message in blade, that's why redirect's didn't work, I actually have to handle them in Vue